# If I upload my code to GitHub can heroku edit the files

Tags: heroku

I creating a discord not the connects to an API. I need to deploy this bot and I heard about heroku as a free alternative to digital ocean and such. I need heroku to edit files because the python file read and writes data to files like keys, bans and json files. I ask this question in the python discord server but have little help as because the people helping me were in experienced with heroku. I will be using the basic plan I need to know if heroku can only run I file and can update GitHub repository or branch. Some of my friends and fellow helper on the python discord server told me that heroku is not the best service to host bots. Is heroku VPS service and are there other alternatives that are good for hosting bots.

I have not yet tried anything and scared to make an account because of the information I have heard I would just like to clarify this before I create an account with heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is not free or cheap as compared to Digital ocean or other cloud services like AWS or GCP. I would recommend you to go with AWS as you will have full control over operating system and is cost effective.